# Windows Firewall Statistics

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I am running Windows native firewall on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I am looking for a way to get statistics, as the number of time that each rule has been fired etc.

I can't find anything in the user interface or a log file... Is it possible to get such statistics or should I use another firewall?